# Handling Database Warnings with Talend

Tags: database, warnings, constraints, talend

I'm receiving this warning message when I insert several data from a CSV file in a Database Table (the violation of a Constraint):

**ORA-00001: unique constraint (XXXX.TABLE_UK_1) violated**

How can I "ignore" the row that is causing this warning, and continue processing the remaining data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although It's never recommended to ignore Oracle errors, as they often reveals more serious ETL or data model mistakes, if you use a tOracleOutput component you can "ignore" them disabling the option "Die on Error": the subjob will complete for error-free rows. You can retrieve the rejected rows with a Row -> Rejected connection.

Comment: I wasn't able to use the "Reject" connection because the Batch option was selected. But now I can use that option, and I can see the Rejected rows. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Scenarios, where the **csv** has duplicate records,you could effectively filter using the **tUniqRow** component before the insert to db.This could potentially prevent the **exception** itself.